# lxml 3.1.2 and lxml2 both on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, lxml, pip

I want to install lxml 3.1.2 on my ubuntu 12.04. It already has lxml2 installed through the package manager. Has anyone already done the double install of lxml with success?

I'm a little worried about confusing my installation, mainly because my installation seems confusing!

I read the docs:

> Using lxml with python-libxml2
>
> If you want to use lxml together with the official libxml2 Python
>   bindings (maybe because one of your dependencies uses it), you must
>   build lxml statically. Otherwise, the two packages will interfere in
>   places where the libxml2 library requires global configuration, which
>   can have any kind of effect from disappearing functionality to crashes
>   in either of the two. To get a static build, either pass the
>   --static-deps option to the setup.py script, or run pip with the STATIC_DEPS or STATICBUILD environment variable set to true, i.e.
>   STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml The STATICBUILD environment variable
>   is handled equivalently to the STATIC_DEPS variable, but is used by
>   some other extension packages, too.

So I'm ready to run

```
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
```

But I hesitate. Suppose this works, how do I distinguish in a python program which lxml I am using?

```
import lxml
```

Will get me which lxml?

Right now, *pip freeze lxml* gives me lxml==2.3.2

I don't know now whether that is from the pip install or the ubuntu package...

With dpkg -L python-lxml, I get many files, among which are:

```
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/not-zip-safe
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/top_level.txt
> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
```

as well as:

```
> /usr/share/pyshared/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info
> /usr/share/pyshared/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/not-zip-safe
> /usr/share/pyshared/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
> /usr/share/pyshared/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
> /usr/share/pyshared/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/top_level.txt
> /usr/share/pyshared/lxml-2.3.2.egg-info/PKG-INF
```

when I use lxml, from which of these (or elsewhere?) is it coming from?

Mystery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out which lxml is loaded running

```
$ python -c "import lxml; print lxml.__file__"
```

In case you want to use several versions of same package, you might find [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) useful. In fact, it is useful even without this condition.

To simplify usage of virtual environments, you migth want to use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). 
Then you can simply switch with:

```
$ workon lxml232
(lxml232) $ python -c "import lxml.etree; print lxml.etree.__version__"
2.3.2
(lxml232) $ workon lxm312
(lxml312) $ python -c "import lxml.etree; print lxml.etree.__version__"
3.1.2
```

Comment: Virtualenv seems like a good way to go, and not mentioned at the lxml site. I think that will probably be the solution. The site seems to be saying that the two can be in the same environment.... Thanks for the python tip! /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/__init__.pyc runs on my system....

Comment: As I suspected, there are some complications in using system packages and pip packages: https://workaround.org/easy-install-debian. Very messy!

Comment: that's why we always leave preinstalled packages to os and work in virtualenv right from the word go

Comment: I think your suggestion is the answer -- and really the only way to go under ubuntu, to avoid conflicts with the package manager. I need to see what happens when I try to interface with something outside virtualenv.

Comment: @wgw I think this discussion is out of scope of original question. For future reference I'd suggest to clean it from those unrelated comments. And if you feel your question is answered, you can accept [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Almost! Part of the original question was: "Has anyone already done the double install of lxml with success?" The lxml suggests a dual install...Not sure why they don't talk about virtualenv...

Comment: the last output in answer is from a real ubuntu server (don't feel lack of test envs), I just removed some sensetive data and renamed env names). Didn't test thoughroughly, only that `etree` can be imported.